# How to publish IPv6 on duckdns

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6, dynamic-dns

My ISP recently started providing IPv6. I have a Raspi with PiVPN at home and like to be able to reach my LAN when I am away. I have been using [DuckDNS](https://duckdns.org) for years now and for IPv4 it worked great. However, because they are on AWS, it seems they are unable to resolve IPv6, so you have to provide it yourself to their update API. This API usually returns `OK` if everything was fine and `KO` if there was an issue.

This is the code I am using to update:

```bsh
token='mytoken'
domain='mydomain'
ipv6=$(ip addr show dev "eth0" | sed -e's/^.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)\/.*$/\1/;t;d' | grep -v '^fd00' | grep -v '^fe80' | head -1)

echo url="https://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=$domain&token=$token&ip=&ip6v=$ipv6&clear=true&verbose=true" | curl -k -o ~/duckdns/duckdns.log -K -
```

I compared my "local" ipv6 and one I get from curling another server as described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1052523), but there seems to be no difference so I am pretty sure I correctly get my IPv6.

It returns an `OK` but then says that I provided an invalid IP when I try to check it on the website.

Any ideas on how to add IPv6 to a duckdns domain?

Comment: Try escaping your IPv6 address before you put it into the URL.  : is a reserved character.  Replace all the : with `%3A`, e.g via `sed 's/:/%3A/g'`

I can confirm that your method to get the ipv6 address seems to work.  That said, I'd recommend grepping for 'scope global' - that will get your routable address and skip the link-local (fe80) and ULA (fd00) addresses.

Comment: @DanPritts Hi I just tried your solution. It results in an ipv6 like: `2a02%3A8388%3Axxxx%3Aae00%3Axxxx%3Aebff%3Axxxx%3A6c24`, so that seems okay. When I try to update duckdns, I get back `OK NOCHANGE` but on duckdns.org I still get the error: `error: invalid ipv6 address entered for MYDOMAIN.duckdns.org`. Did you get ipv6 updates to work on duckdns?

Comment: No, i don't use duckdns - that's why i left it as a "try this".

Comment: I improved the `grep` pipe to also exclude `fc00::/7` addresses, and changed the sed marker from `/` to `!` for clearer visibility since there's an escaped `/` in the expression: 
```ipv6=$(ip addr show dev "enp6s0" | sed -e 's!.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)\/.*$!\1!;t;d' | grep -v '^fc' | grep -v '^fd00' | grep -v '^fe80' | head -1)```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So for some reason, the way to publish an IP as recommended by DuckDNS themselves under the install-tab doesn't work. If you change the line doing `curl` from parsing echo through stdout and setting an url variable to just constructing the string and curling that, it works:

```bsh
curl -s "https://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=$domain&token=$token&ip=&ipv6=$ipv6addr" -o ~/duckdns/duckdns.log
```

This version will let DuckDNS figure out your IPv4 and set your IPv6 according to what your device configured itself to as shown in the question. Make sure to run the script regularly as your global IPv6 may change if a NDP finds a conflicting address or if you haven't set a static IPv6.

Comment: According to the [spec](https://www.duckdns.org/spec.jsp), if you specify the `ipv6` update parameter, IPv4 automatic detection is not performed. So you do need to specify the IPv4 address explicitly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Run this script periodically using crontab

duck.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
domain=mydomain
token=aaaabbbb-cccc-4444-8888-ddeeff001122
ipv6addr=$(curl -s https://api6.ipify.org)
ipv4addr=$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org)
echo "https://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=$domain&token=$token&ip=$ipv4addr&ipv6=$ipv6addr"
curl -s "https://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=$domain&token=$token&ip=$ipv4addr&ipv6=$ipv6addr" -o ~/duckdns/duckdns.log
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary calls to another API?

Comment: To get around NAT. Machines need not be aware of their Public IPs.

Comment: That's only half-correct. For IPv6 there is no need for NAT, there's plenty of addresses. Some may do it to hide their machines, but that's enterprise intranet stuff and not something your ISP would do, as it's extra work for no benefit. And for IPv4 that would be correct, but duckdns.org will know your public IP anyway, otherwise it couldn't respond to your package. So if you leave that IPv4 field empty, duckdns will figure it out by itself, as described in the install docs.